# How add alamofire in Xcode10.2.1 using Swift5

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I want to use `Alamofire` in my project

I have tried to install `Podfile` but confused `Alamofire` version to install.
when I try to install `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.5'` I'm getting this error

> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Alamofire":
>     In Podfile:
>       Alamofire (~> 5.0.0-beta.5)

know I have installed pod `'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.3'` but when I try to import in my `ViewController.swift` file getting the error `No such module Alamofire`

Comment: What's your project deployment target.

Comment: It's not necessarily to specify exact version of the pod, you can just write `pod 'Alamofire'`, before import in your `ViewController` you should build your project, if build doesn't help you, try to reopen your project, hope it will help you.

Comment: @A.Munzer it's 10.0

Comment: check this link for answer this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912541/why-do-i-keep-getting-the-error-no-such-module-realmswift/55915886#55915886

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the more recent `podspec` for Alamofire 5.0.0 beta ([just here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Alamofire.podspec)), your project must fill this requirements:

`s.swift_version = '5.0'`

and

`s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'` (i suppose you're developing for iOS)

a `Podfile` with single line:

`'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.6'`

is working on me

Comment: thanks but I'm getting this error `framework not found Alamofire`

Comment: @Ugas Please go through this answer to solve it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417151/no-such-module-alamofire-xcode-wont-recognize-alamofire-framework